# Ubuntu 16.04 LTS - Freeze after out of fullscreen mode (YouTube, Netflix, and others)

Tags: 16.04, google-chrome, video, youtube, fullscreen

I have a bug: When I watch a video on YouTube, Netflix or other site in FullScreen mode, and then when I exit from this fullscreen, and go back normal. My screen freezes on my computer on the right side and down side screen of the screen. My mouse and Sound are still working (video is playing forward), but the image stop and thenI can't go back to fullscreen. And my computer has no reaction until I restart it and the problem is gone until I go back to fullscreen again.

Dell Latitude E6410
Ram: 8GB
SDD: 500GB

Problem on browsers Google Chrome and Firefox.

Answer (score -1):

For the bug, I have it too, and to close the chrome tab without restarting, here are the steps.

1. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>
2. Type this code, `ps -aux | grep -inE <your browser name, ie chrome>`
3. Find the pid (process id number) it should be right after your username
4. Write `kill <process id number>` for instance if your pid is 24556 then you would run `kill 24556`
5. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F7</kbd>

The browser should close without you restarting.

Comment: I tried to add the image so you can see the problem. Cause I don't know if it's my Ubuntu or the browser

Comment: It is a factor of both. It is I think the resolution when full screen that lags Ubuntu. As far as I know, there is no absolute way of solving the problem, but the steps above allows you to kill the browser without restarting.

Comment: Thank you for helping me, that explains why sometimes it lags when going in and out of fullscreen

Comment: Your'e welcome, any time.